# Regular Expression Not Finding all numbers in a list

Tags: regex

`RegEx034 = re.compile(r'\b(([034])-(?!\2)([034])-(?!\2|\3)[034])\b')`

My issue is that the regular expression I am using is catching only the first 12 numbers out of the entire 24 numbers in the list. The list I attached shows that the first 12 are a match. The bottom 12 numbers did not match when I used the regular expression. I need to capture the entire list with the regular expression I am using. Please let me know if I am missing anything. I am looking to identify 034 regardless of the fourth number.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your sample text _as text_ instead of an image ([why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612)).

Comment: Try ``^(?=.*([034])(?:-\d)?-(?!\1)([034])(?:-\d)?-(?!\1|\2))\d(?:-\d){3}$`` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mgUZk9/1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`\b[034]-(?:\d-)?[034]-(?:\d-)?[034]\b`